# generate dynamic table rows using XQuery

Tags: xslt, xquery, marklogic

I have a function which returns phone numbers. It returns in this format

```
<td>#phone</td>
```

The function may return any number of values.
I want to display them in a grid like structure.
i.e a table which has say 10 columns in it. (So if the function returns 26 records, then I will have 3 rows: two rows with 10 columns and third row with 6 columns.)

I am unable to understand the counter logic in for statement in XQuery (for statement with keyword at). Any help would be appreciated.

The function call is like this (any modification to the function call is also highly appreciated):

The actual code is this:

```
declare function local:table-construct(
  $areacode as xs:string, 
  $uniquekey as $xs:string, 
  $doc as xs:element) as xs:element?
{
  for $phno in $doc/users[$areacode eq $code and $uniquekey eq $thiskey]
  return <td>{$phno/phone}</td>
}

let $doc := <an xml doc from a database>
let $areacode := "somestring"
let $uniquekey := "somekey"
return 
  <html>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>{local:table-construct($areacode, $uniquekey, $doc)}</tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The present format gives me all the phone numbers in the same row. I want the table to show only 10 rows. and the remaining data in the next rows.

Comment: Can you show the actual XQuery code you are using?

Comment: @grtjn please check , i have added the code in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't provide any code, I can only guess you trapped into the "functional programming" trap. XQuery is a functional language without variables as known in imperative languages, better think of them as constants.

```
let $x := 1 to 10
let $sum := 0
for $i in $x
let $sum := $sum+$i (: here we cover $sum from line 2, do not change it :)
return $sum
```

The output of this code is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` which might be unexpected. In line 4, we always add `$i` (1 to 10) and `$sum` (0), but we do not update `$sum` but cover it. For the next `$i`, `$sum` will be 0 again.

If this is the problem, think about using some pattern like this:

```
let $seq := 1 to 15
let $dividor := 4
for $i in 1 to ceiling(count($seq) div $dividor) cast as xs:integer
return <tr>{
  for $td in subsequence($seq, ($i -1)*$dividor + 1, $dividor)
  return <td>{$td}</td>
}</tr>
```

You might have to fit it to your code, but the idea should be fine.

EDIT: If your query processor supported it, you also could use a [sliding window](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-xquery-11-20080711/#N1432D). As of version 5.0.2, Marklogic still doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Ranon. you were spot on.  I was indeed trapped in "functional programming trap". This really helped in understanding the whole logic behind counters.

Answer (score 0):

mabe this can help, u can do the grouping as per your request inside the xslt!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="Columns" select="10"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="phone[position() mod $Columns= 1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="phone">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select=". | following-sibling::phone[position() &lt; $Columns]"/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="line" mode="copy">
    <td><xsl:copy-of select="."/><td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Treemonkey. I was always looking at XSL as second option but anyways thanks for responding and appreciate the help !

Answer (score 0):

The at keyword of the `FLWOR` statement won't help you much here. You need to take 10 columns at a time and put that in its own `<tr>`. The most straight-forward way of doing this in MarkLogic is as follows:

```
declare function local:wrap-columns($columns, $width) {
  let $nrrows := ceiling(count($columns) div $width)
  for $row in 1 to $nrrows
  let $start := ($row - 1) * $width + 1
  let $end := $row * $width
  return
    <tr>{$columns[$start to $end]}</tr>
};

let $columns :=
  for $i in 1 to 26
  return <td>{$i}</td>
return
  local:wrap-columns($columns, 10)
```

On second glance, it resembles the solution by Ranon (coincidence, honestly), though wrapped in a function to make integration and reuse easier.

A solution in `XSLT` would work too, but if you are not already using `XSLT`, then using `XQuery` makes more sense here I guess.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful in understanding the counter logic. Appreciate the help.